# Python xml ElementTree: find values of only first 3 elements with same name

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to parse an xml response and save specific data to a list.

XML

```
<ack>Success</ack>
<version>1.13.0</version>
<data>
 <name>AAAA</name>
 <age>00</age>
<data>
 <name>BBBB</name>
 <age>11</age>
<data>
 <name>CCCC</name>
 <age>22</age>
.
.
.
.
<data>
 <name>ZZZZ</name>
 <age>999</age>
```

I'm using ElementTree to parse the xml.

My script

```
import requests, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

e = requests.get('http://sample.com/xml')

#parse the response and get root
eroot = ET.fromstring(e.text)

#iterate over root and extract data
names = [ p.find('name').text for p in eroot.iter('data') ]

print(names)
```

I can extract all the name elements using the above script but the xml response contains a lot of name elements. I need only the first three names.

I used list comprehension to reduce the lines of code.

My questions

- How do I get only the first three names without parsing all the names in the xml.
- Can I use any loop to restrict the p.find to 3 iterations?
- Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

names = [ p.find('name').text for p in islice(eroot.iter('data'), 0, 3)]
```